# A generalization of the Parry circle theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I found a conjectures of generalization of the Parry circle theorem a more than year ago, but I no a found solution for the conjectures.  I'm an electrical engineer, I am not a mathematician. I don't know how to prove this result. Could you give a proof?

**[Parry circle theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parry_point_%28triangle%29)** Let $ABC$ be a triangle, [the triangle centroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid.html), [the first and the second isodynamic points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsodynamicPoints.html), [the far-out point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Far-OutPoint.html), [the focus of the Kiepert parabola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KiepertParabola.html), [the Parry point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParryPoint.html) and two points in Kimberling centers $X(352)$ and $X(353)$ lie on a circle.

**A generalization of Parry theorem:** Let a rectangular circumhyperbola of ABC, let $L$ be the isogonal conjugate line of the hyperbola. The tangent line to the hyperbola at [the orthoencenter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html) meets $L$ at point $K$. The line through $K$ and center of the hyperbola meets the hyperbola at $F_+$, $F_-$.  Let  $ I_+$, $I_-$, $G$ be the isogonal conjugate of $F_+, F_-$ and $K$ respectively. Let $F$ be the inverse point of $G$ with respect to the circumcircle of $ABC$. Then five points $I_+$, $I_-$, $G$,[X(110)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KiepertParabola.html), $F$ lie on a circle. Furthermore $K$ lie on the Jerabek hyperbola.

[image]
When the hyperbolar is the Kiepert hyperbola the conjecture be comes Parry circle theorem. (see 1, 2)

1-https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/AdvancedPlaneGeometry/conversations/messages/2255
2-http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1645609